# Minimal Conflict in Artificial Intelligence

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Consider the knowledge base

```
false :- a.
false :- b,c.
a :- d.
b :- e.
c :- d,f.
c :- g.
c :- h.
```

Given that {d,e,f,g,h} is the set of assumables, what is the set of minimal conflicts for the above clauses?

I got

```
{d}
{e,f}
{e,g}
{e,h}
```

Is that correct? Not 100% sure I understand minimal conflict.

Answer (score 0):

> A **conflict** of KB is a set of assumables that, given KB imply false.

But this equal definition may seems more understandable:

> A **conflict set** is a set of assumables that cannot be all true given the observation.

And a **minimal conflict** is a conflict such that no strict subset is also a conflict.

Accordingly the minimal conflict sets for this KB are exactly:

> {d}
>   {e,f}
>   {e,g}
>   {e,h}

To be sure:

- In any of these sets all the assubable(s) cannot be true at the same time.
- None of these sets has a subset which is a conflict too.

To complete the answer, here is the truth table for p → q

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer is incorrect as far as I know.

The minimal conflict sets for this KB are exactly:

```
{d}
{e,g}
{e,h}
```

As for the previous answer e,f,d is a conflict but not minimal because of the d subset being a conflict. e,f is nothing.